# Is it normal for echo json_encode to return the last value

Tags: php, arrays, json, database, mysqli

```
<?php

require_once("Connection.php");

class DisplayJsonData{

    function getAllJsonData(){

        $connection = new Connection();
        $conn = $connection->getConnection();

        $jsonData = array();


        try{

            $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM DataTable";
            $getJson = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getJson)){

                $jsonData = $row;

            }


        }catch (Exception $e){
            echo "Error while displaying json : " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        if($sqlQuery){
            echo json_encode(array("DATA"=>$jsonData));
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array("DATA"=>null));
        }
    }
}

$json = new DisplayJsonData();
$json->getAllJsonData();

?>
```

here is my code its working,I would like to get a confirmation,

```
echo json_encode(array("DATA"=>$jsonData));
```

this line is returning one value the last value from the array list but I have 8 records in database,now does it return all the values but i cannot see them since i only wrote the name of the array but i am not looping in it,is that what is going on,or is it really writing 1 record.

Comment: You were just updating the value of $jsonData with the while loop. Therefore, the last $row will be the value of $jsonData. You should push the $row to $jsonData instead.

Comment: Also, you can try: $jsonData = mysqli_fetch_all($getJson, MYSQLI_ASSOC); without the WHILE loop. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Your test `if($sqlQuery){` will always pass as this is the query string and not if the query executed correctly.

Comment: Also as a matter of style - I would normally `return` the data from the function and output from the calling point.  Functions that `echo` their own data can cause unwanted side effects at times.

Comment: @Nigel Ren I am actually trying to send it to my android device from a host,so looking beautiful is not my concern right now let alone to make it readable i can use echo `json_encode(array("DATA"=>$jsonData),JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`       I can add `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` which makes it readable.

Comment: It's not about 'looking beautiful', it's about coding style.  The method is called `getAllJsonData` - and that's all I would expect it to do.  When you have different classes and methods echoing data directly it can be difficult to control the overall result.

Comment: @NigelRen oh that thing,the echo is just for testing purposes i will remove echo in the future i just wanted to see how the data look inside the file,I am not building a website,I am building an android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is over writing the `$jsonData` variable therefore all you see is the last row added to that variable. Add the `[]` to the array name and each time round the loop you will add a new occurance to the array.

Try this

```
$jsonData=array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($getJson)){
    $jsonData[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you have reason, sorry , i see that like a “simple error” , in my next answers i will explain better.

Answer (score 1):

NO, it is not normal for [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to return the last value. You've a problem with the variable **$jsonData** it should be an array and on every while loop iteration that **$row** must be append/pushed to that **$jsonData** array. with this line `$jsonData = $row;` you're overwriting every row value so in that case when encode it to json only the last row is available.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getJson)){
       $jsonData[] = $row;  //see the extra []
}
```

So now if you echo you data like this you should get 8 rows perfectly.

```
 echo json_encode(array("DATA"=>$jsonData));
```